# Eclipse / M2E reset Deployment Assembly on each Update Maven Project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I have been having numerous problems with Eclipse on two different Macs since Eclipse upgraded to 2022-09 (4.25.0). After many fresh installs and imports, I am still having an issue with with the Maven plugin and Maven dependencies.

Maven Integration for Eclipse (2.0.4.20220904-1703) is installed. Eclipse is launched with Java 17, a requirement for M2E 2.0.1 and above. The Maven Nature is present. The facet Dynamic Web Module 4.0 is enabled with Tomcat 9.0 as its runtime. I added Maven Dependencies equal to `WEB-INF/lib` to the Deployment Assembly. Doing so adds `<attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>` to the `MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER` `<classpathentry>` in my project's `.classpath` file.

However, if I select Project -> Update Maven Project, Eclipse (or M2E) removes Maven Dependencies from the Deployment Assembly, removes the `org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency` attribute from `MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER`, and deletes the *.jar files from my project in Tomcat `wtpwebapps/myapp/WEB-INF/lib`. Of course my app will not deploy properly if I start the server.

The workaround I've hit on is to open `./classpath` in a text editor and add `<attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>` to `MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER`. Then when the server starts the correct *.jar files are copied to `wtpwebapps/myapp/WEB-INF/lib` and my app runs.

These steps are perfectly repeatable--I've done it many times. I've tried different combinations of Maven preferences, and still it happens exactly this way. The project's `pom.xml` is complete; it compiles, tests, and packages the project perfectly. Why is this Eclipse error happening? Why is M2E resetting the Deployment Attributes, and how can I stop this from happening? I've tried setting `.classpath` to read-only, but then Maven will not update my project. It insists on stomping the correct settings.

BTW, I see this problem *frequently* described here, but for much older versions of Eclipse and M2E (some going back over 10 years). I've exhausted myself trying various recommendations. The closest I've come is the workaround described above.

Comment: Is "Maven Integration for WTP" also installed?

Comment: If you use maven you should only add libraries as maven dependencies and not change the deployment assembly yourself

Comment: @nitind Yes, m2e-wtp (1.5.2.20220906-1452) is installed.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen The libraries are in the pom.xml. Opening the project's Properties, they are in the Java Build Path, Libraries tab, and in the Run Configuration, Source tab, under Default. All without action on my part. However they do not appear in `wtpwebapps/myapp/WEB-INF/lib` without being in the Deployment Assembly and this is not happening unless I put them  there myself with Add -> Java Build Path Entries -> Maven Dependencies.

Comment: I see.  Can you make this public on GitHub or similar for experimentation, or create a minimal viable project showing this behavior?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I cannot put it on GitHub because it and many of its libraries are proprietary/commercial. I can try to duplicate it next week, but in 15 years I've found duplicating anything of that size in Eclipse nigh impossible. It actually works on my MacBook, and I've compared every dialog and library I can think but no luck. I don't understand how the same install steps on two different machines can create two different installations, or require updating different plugins.

Comment: @thad different versions of eclipse perhaps?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248324/discussion-between-thad-and-thorbjorn-ravn-andersen).

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to latest udpate-site https://download.eclipse.org/m2e-wtp/releases/latest/ and update m2e-wtp.
I had the same problem, the update solved it!

Answer (score 0):

I am using Eclipse 2021-03(4.19) and having the same problem(missing Maven dependencies in Eclipse's "Deployment Assembly" tab after "Maven --> update project"). However, when I update the pom.xml to use

```
<maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
<maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
```

, the Maven dependencies in Eclipse's "Deployment Assembly" tab WON'T be removed after "Maven --> update project" !

I then try restoring original pom.xml settings as

```
<maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
<maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
```

, the Maven dependencies in Eclipse's "Deployment Assembly" tab again WILL be removed after "Maven --> update project" !

Not sure what happend inside Eclipse or m2e-wtp, but for your reference.